# MvvmCross EnsureSingletonAvailable and EnsureInitialized

Tags: android, initialization, mvvmcross

Does anyone know what the methods

```
var setup = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(Application.Context);
setup.EnsureInitialized();
```

actually call in the set up process. I am getting an error to say that has failed to resolve a parameter when calling

```
Mvx.Resolve<IType>()
```

I'm assuming that it is not calling a method in the App class that I am using to register the type in question.

Any ideas? Could this be a race condition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the actual implementation: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Core/MvxSetupSingleton.cs#L96. Where are you getting that error? Is your app crashing on the line which calls EnsureInitialized?

Comment: I moved the code that was not getting called into App.Initilize() and this solved the problem